# App crashes passing data between activity, null pointer exception

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android development, sorry if this is a fundamental problem I should be able to solve myself. I have read through many other questions that's how I ended up initiating the switch everywhere I could think of but I still haven't fixed it.

I'm making a chess game with the functionality to record games if the user puts a switch in one activity to the "ON" position.

**Error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
'boolean android.widget.Switch.isChecked()' on a null object reference at
com.android51.HomeActivity.toRecord(HomeActivity.java:43)
```

This is how I passed that value when the Chess activity starts.

```
public void toChess(View view){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Chess.class);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    Boolean recordState = bundle.getBoolean("recordState");
    HomeActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}

public void toRecord(View view){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, RecordActivity.class);
    Switch recordSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.toggle_record);

    Boolean recordState = recordSwitch.isChecked(); <---- NULL POINTER, WHY?

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean("recordState", recordState);
    myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    HomeActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

I have the switch inside `onCreate()` like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);

    switch_record = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.toggle_record);
    recordState = switch_record.isChecked();
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.android51.HomeActivity">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/toggle_record"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:switchPadding="170dp"
        android:text="Record All Gameplay"
        android:checked="true"
        android:onClick="onSwitchButtonClicked"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
```

Comment: can you post your XML code for activity_record.xml ? I want to see the View with id 'toggle_record'

Comment: But why you find id of it in toRecord method? It should be done onCreate

Comment: Is this XML accessible by this activity?

Comment: @okset but the switch only lives in my Record Activity, if I called it from home it wouldn't know about the switch right?

Comment: @Arunava oh how does that work! That sounds like it could be my problem

Comment: Is this xml file `R.layout.activity_record`?

Comment: Try removing this line `Switch recordSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.toggle_record);` then using `Boolean recordState = switch_record.isChecked()` inside toRecord()

Comment: @Bmbariah how would it know about the existence of switch_record? It didn't work

Comment: @anthony yes the XML above is for activity_record